# Facebook Permission to Show Timeline

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am a WordPress theme developer and want to add one feature to my theme where my theme users can be able to display their own Facebook post/timeline inside their own website.

So the scenario is as follows:
Anyone who uses my theme then they can display their own Facebook timeline in their own website through our App that included in my theme. What is the correct permission to accommodate this need?

More than 3 times I tried to request the "**user_posts**" permission but always rejected. They said:

> We were unable to approve your app because your submitted use case for
> the permissions requested is unclear or invalid for use. Please refer
> to the permission decision for more details.

Please help and thanks

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/user_posts explains what the allowed use cases are. If they disagree on whether what you are trying to do fits those, you can only try and explain better, why you think otherwise, I suppose.